# Why do I receive the warning "Using uninitialized memory" for a return value from "OpenThread"?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2022

This is the warning-producing code:

```cpp
HANDLE thread_handle = ::OpenThread((THREAD_SUSPEND_RESUME | THREAD_GET_CONTEXT | THREAD_SET_CONTEXT), TRUE, current_thread_entry_32.th32ThreadID);

if ((thread_handle == nullptr) || (thread_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE))
    continue;

::SuspendThread(thread_handle);
```

This code produces the warning `C6001 Using uninitialized memory '*thread_handle'.` on the variable `thread_handle` in the line `::SuspendThread(thread_handle);`:

[image: warning]

Why does Intellisense/the compiler think `thread_handle` is uninitialized here?
As far as I know `HANDLE` is a `void*` and `OpenThread` returns a `HANDLE` so it should never be uninitialized, should it?

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 with the `/std:c++20` flag set.

As requested here is a minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

void main()
{
    HANDLE toolhelp_32_snapshot_handle = ::CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, ::GetCurrentProcessId());

    if ((toolhelp_32_snapshot_handle == nullptr) || (toolhelp_32_snapshot_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE))
        return;

    THREADENTRY32 current_thread_entry_32 = {};

    ::ZeroMemory(&current_thread_entry_32, sizeof(current_thread_entry_32));

    current_thread_entry_32.dwSize = sizeof(current_thread_entry_32);

    if (::Thread32First(toolhelp_32_snapshot_handle, &current_thread_entry_32) == FALSE)
        return;

    do
    {
        if ((current_thread_entry_32.th32OwnerProcessID != ::GetCurrentProcessId()) || (current_thread_entry_32.th32ThreadID == ::GetCurrentThreadId()))
            continue;

        HANDLE thread_handle = ::OpenThread((THREAD_SUSPEND_RESUME | THREAD_GET_CONTEXT | THREAD_SET_CONTEXT), TRUE, current_thread_entry_32.th32ThreadID);

        if ((thread_handle == nullptr) || (thread_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE))
            continue;

        ::SuspendThread(thread_handle); // thread_handle produces the warning here

        CONTEXT thread_context = {};

        ::ZeroMemory(&thread_context, sizeof(thread_context));

        thread_context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS;

        ::GetThreadContext(thread_handle, &thread_context);

        thread_context.Dr0 = 0x01020304;
        thread_context.Dr7 = 0x01;

        ::SetThreadContext(thread_handle, &thread_context);
        ::ResumeThread(thread_handle);
        ::CloseHandle(thread_handle);
    } while (::Thread32Next(toolhelp_32_snapshot_handle, &current_thread_entry_32));

    ::CloseHandle(toolhelp_32_snapshot_handle);
}
```

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Comment: the warning complains about `*thread_handle`. Just because a pointer is initialized does not imply that it points to an initialized object. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: No repro on VS2019 version 16.11.5.  Looks like a regression of [this older issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Spurious-warning-C6001-Using-uninitial/1299941?space=8&q=C6001+handle), pretty common for new VS releases.  Remind them of it with Help > Send Feedback.

Comment: not direct related, but check `(thread_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)` senseless and better remove this. like and `(toolhelp_32_snapshot_handle == nullptr)` senseless check

Comment: Per the documentation, `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` can only return `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` on failure, and `OpenThread()` can only return `NULL` (`nullptr`) on failure. Also, you are leaking the snapshot if `Thread32First()` fails.